# Refactoring advice, which design pattern to use

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

Suppose I have an ancestor class (TMyAncestorClass), an enumerated type (TMyType) and some descendants class (TDesc1, TDesc2, TDesc3...)

```
type TMytype = (ta, tb, tc);

TMyAncestorClass= class
  procedure DoSomething;
end;

TDesc1 = class(TMyAncestorClass)
end;

TDesc2 = class(TMyAncestorClass)
end;

TDesc3 = class(TMyAncestorClass)
end;

function CreateMyClass(aMyType: TMyType): TMyAncestorClass;
begin
  case aMyType of
    ta: Result := TDesc1.Create;
    tb: Result := TDesc2.Create;
    tc: Result := TDesc3.Create;
  else
    Result := nil; // or throw an exception
  end;
end;
```

I want to refactor it. What is the best design pattern or solution for it? Now every time a new type is added I have to modify a CreateMyClass function too.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a "bad" pattern.

Comment: I'd always add an `else` to any `case` which yields right in your face that something was forgotten to be implemented. The only exception is `case Boolean of TRUE: ; FALSE: ; end;`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an enumerated type, simply use the class type:

```
TMyType = class of TMyAncestorClass;
```

Then your function becomes trivial:

```
function CreateMyClass(aMyType: TMyType): TMyAncestorClass;
begin
    Result := TMyType.Create;
end;
```

You call it like this:

```
var
    X : TMyAncestroClass;
begin
    X := CreateMyClass(TDesc1);
end;
```

Of course this is somewhat useless as is. But I guess you have a lot of other code in CreateMyClass(). BTW: I would have named it MyClassFactory.

**Edit:**

If you really need an enumerated type, then use the following additional code:

```
type
    TMyTypeEnum = (ta, tb, tc);
const
    MyTypes : array [TMyTypeEnum] of TMyType = (TDesc1, TDesc2, TDesc3);
```

The class factory is then:

```
function MyClassFactory(aMyType : TMyTypeEnum) : TMyAncestorClass;
begin
    Result := MyTypes[aMyType].Create;
end;
```

And call it like this:

```
var
    X : TMyAncestroClass;
begin
    X := MyClassFactory(tb);
end;
```

Comment: I need definitely by enumerated type, not class types.

Comment: @Steve88 I have edited my answer to add simple code to use an enumerated type that I name TMyTypeEnum.

Answer (score 2):

You could get rid of the enum completely by simply having `CreateMyClass()` take an `integer` instead, eg:

```pascal
unit MyClasses;

interface

type
  TMyAncestorClass = class
    procedure DoSomething; virtual; abstract;
  end;

function CreateMyClass(aMyType: Integer): TMyAncestorClass;

implementation

type
  TDesc1 = class(TMyAncestorClass)
    procedure DoSomething; override;
  end;

  TDesc2 = class(TMyAncestorClass)
    procedure DoSomething; override;
  end;

  TDesc3 = class(TMyAncestorClass)
    procedure DoSomething; override;
  end;

...

function CreateMyClass(aMyType: Integer): TMyAncestorClass;
begin
  case aMyType of
    1: Result := TDesc1.Create;
    2: Result := TDesc2.Create;
    3: Result := TDesc3.Create;
  else
    Result := nil; // or throw an exception
  end;
end;

end.
```

```pascal
var
  Obj: TMyAncestorClass;
begin
  Obj := CreateMyClass(1, 2, 3, ...);
  try
    Obj.DoSomething;
  finally
    Obj.Free;
  end;
end;
```

You could simplify that a little by using an array of class types, eg:

```pascal
unit MyClasses;

interface

type
  TMyAncestorClass = class
    constructor Create; virtual; // <-- add this
    procedure DoSomething; virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TMyAncestorClassType = class of TMyAncestorClass;

function CreateMyClass(aMyType: Integer): TMyAncestorClass;

implementation

type
  TDesc1 = class(TMyAncestorClass)
    constructor Create; override; // if needed
    procedure DoSomething; override;
  end;

  TDesc2 = class(TMyAncestorClass)
    constructor Create; override; // if needed
    procedure DoSomething; override;
  end;

  TDesc3 = class(TMyAncestorClass)
    constructor Create; override; // if needed
    procedure DoSomething; override;
  end;

...

constructor TMyAncestorClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;
end;

function CreateMyClass(aMyType: Integer): TMyAncestorClass;
const
  Types: array[1..3] of TMyAncestorClassType = (
    TDesc1,
    TDesc2,
    TDesc3
  );
begin
  if aMyType >= Low(Types) and aMyType <= High(Types) then
    Result := Types[aMyType].Create
  else
    Result := nil; // or throw an exception
end;

end.
```

```pascal
var
  Obj: TMyAncestorClass;
begin
  Obj := CreateMyClass(1, 2, 3, ...);
  try
    Obj.DoSomething;
  finally
    Obj.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Of course, this does mean you are still having to edit `CreteMyClass()` each time a new class is introduced. So, if you want something more dynamic, you will need to add a registration system at runtime, for example by storing class types in a lookup table like `TDictionary`, eg:

```pascal
unit MyClasses;

interface

type
  TMyAncestorClass = class
    constructor Create; virtual;
    procedure DoSomething; virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TMyAncestorClassType = class of TMyAncestorClass;

function RegisterMyClass(aClass: TMyAncestorClassType): Integer;
function CreateMyClass(aMyType: Integer): TMyAncestorClass;

implementation

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

var
  RegisteredClasses: TDictionary<Integer, TMyAncestorClassType>;
  Counter: Integer = 0;

constructor TMyAncestorClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;
end;

function RegisterMyClass(aClass: TMyAncestorClassType): Integer;
begin
  Result := Counter;
  Inc(Counter);
  RegisteredClasses.Add(Result, aClass);
end;

function CreateMyClass(aMyType: Integer): TMyAncestorClass;
var
  LClass: TMyAncestorClassType;
begin
  if RegisteredClasses.TryGetValue(aMyType, LClass) then
    Result := LClass.Create
  else
    Result := nil; // or throw an exception
end;

initialization
  RegisteredClasses := TDictionary<Integer, TMyAncestorClassType>.Create;
finalization
  RegisteredClasses.Free;
end.
```

```
uses
  ..., MyClasses;

type
  TDesc1 = class(TMyAncestorClass)
    constructor Create; override; // if needed
    procedure DoSomething; override;
  end;

  TDesc2 = class(TMyAncestorClass)
    constructor Create; override; // if needed
    procedure DoSomething; override;
  end;

  TDesc3 = class(TMyAncestorClass)
    constructor Create; override; // if needed
    procedure DoSomething; override;
  end;

  ...

...

var
  Desc1Type: Integer;
  Desc2Type: Integer;
  Desc3Type: Integer;
  ...

...

var
  Obj: TMyAncestorClass;
begin
  Obj := CreateMyClass(Desc1Type, Desc2Type, Desc3Type, ...);
  ...
  Obj.Free;
end;

...

initialization
  Desc1Type := RegisterMyClass(TDesc1);
  Desc2Type := RegisterMyClass(TDesc2);
  Desc3Type := RegisterMyClass(TDesc3);
```

Comment: Thanks Remy Lebeau. It is a very good example.

Comment: You can do exactly this even without replacing the enumerated type with simple integers (which are far less descriptive and somewhat less type safe).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand The point was to get rid of the enum, though. So it is one less thing to update whenever new classes are added.